# How to log erros in flask app on ubuntu server

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

My flask app is running via gunincron & nginx on an ubuntu server.
I can't find a way to make gunicron to log app erros.

Therefore, I want to create a separated logger, that logs every error that occurs in the app, on a file on the server.

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging in python is mainly implemented via the logging library. It enables you to have different levels of logging for different components of your code. It also enables you to log into files (by default it logs to stdout).

In flask before you run app.run() you can define a file to log to and what log level you want it to be present:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='error.log',level=logging.WARNING)
```

The levels include:

```
CRITICAL

ERROR

WARNING
    
INFO

DEBUG

NOTSET
```

In case you would like to read more, an amazing tutorial about logging/ error handling that helped me along my Flask journey from Miguel Grinberg can be found [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-error-handling).